# Javascript: Redirecting to another site through a popup

Tags: javascript, mybb

I'm quite bad with Javascript and I can't work out a solution I need help to. I'm having a website and I'm trying to make a redirection to another site, but through a popup.

Example :

```
<script>alert(This will prompt up the message)</scrip>

<script>window.location="http://This-will-redirect-me-to-another-link.com";</scrip>
```

Like you can see I could simply use the second javascript to redirect the persons to another page, but due some reasons I can't use it as it will work only for half of the page(the script would be kinda 'sandboxed'), but if I'd make a popup(the first alert script) the second script would get out of the 'sandbox'. Is there anyone who has any ideas how I should implement this or can it be done otherwise with PHP or HTML?

I'm having a MyBB forum and there's a shoutbox for it which I'm using. There's a command which will change the notice of the shoutbox and the command is as such /notice New notice  | But I noted that the new notice can be changed with javascript and it'll work such as /notice js code here | Then I thought that what if I would make such a javascript that would redirect people to another webpage. As I'm having such a forum where it's needed to redirect from the main page to another one, I'd like to apply it. Then Staffs could do it in the forum very well, but there's a problem. by adding

/notice window.location="http://This-will-redirect-me-to-another-link.com";
It'll affect only the shoutbox and shoutbox is being redirected to another webpage, but as an alert works for the whole forum I thought maybe I can redirect them to somewhere else with the alert. I want to know is it possible with just one script then Staffs would be able to do it. I know it's a serious security risk & it can be otherwise also, but I'd really like to experiment with it.

I hope someone can help. :)

Comment: Can you add a new `<button>`, `<span>` or `<a>` to bind the redirect on click (`href` for the `<a>`)? If you're trying to do it with an `alert()` style box, try looking into the `confirm()`.

Comment: If you simply need a link to open in a new window like a "popup" just put a target in your <a> tag (eg target="_new" ). If you want more control over the dimensions of the window use @Yoni's example

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  window.open('url to other site', 'window name', 'width=900,height=650,scrollbars=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you (if not please correct me), you can put **a** tag on popup or another place:

```
<a href="http://another.site.com/" 
    onclick="return confirm('Do you want to see another page?');">Redirect</a>
```